# Mongoose schemas and collections

Tags: node.js, mongodb, collections, mongoose, schema

Hi everyone this is the first time I ask a question in here,

I'm very new into the MEAN stack and by now I'm trying to develop an application using it. As I understand in mongodb an Schema (Database) can have one or more collections (Tables(?)), when I'm using mongoose I define a Song model and an Artist model:

For Song:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema   = mongoose.Schema;

var songSchema = new Schema({
  songName:       { type: String },
  songArtist:     [{type : Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref : 'Artist'}]   
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Song', songSchema);
```

For artist:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema   = mongoose.Schema;

var artistSchema = new Schema({
  artistName:       { type: String }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Artist', artistSchema);
```

My app.js looks like this:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/song', function(err, res) {
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log('Connected to Database');
});

var models = require('./models/song')(app, mongoose);
```

The issue with this is, as I understand and saw, that I'm creating 2 databases/schemas while I want to Create one database/schema and have this two collections in there:

```
SongDatabase:
--- Song
--- Artist
```

How should I do it in this case with my mongoose models/controllers and my app.js? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You only need to issue `mongoose.connect` once in your app and the "database" is defined in the connection string. All collections will be created in that database unless you specifically say otherwise. You seem to be confusing terms here. I would suggest doing some mongoose and MongoDB tutorials first to understand properly. Easy to search for.

Comment: I've searched for several tutorials but all of them use only one connection, would you be able to provide one that looks like what I want to do? (1 db, 2 collections)

Answer (score 0):

I solved all my doubts taking a look into [this tutorial](https://gist.github.com/fwielstra/1025038), as you can see in here they implement two collections within one database (My inicial concern). Once you are connected to the database and you perform a post to the collection you want, in this case thread or post, it will create the collection into mongodb.

Answer (score 0):

The issue there is that your connection string is mongodb://localhost/**song**

**Song** becomes your DB, and within Song you should be able to see two collections 
 - SongS
 - ArtistS

Posible solutions: Flush the database, drop all. Start clean and check what your application is doing. Use another name for the DB